# RabbitMQ SSL Guide...What changes needed for production?

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, ssl-certificate

I followed the RabbitMQ SSL guide meticulously. 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html

And it works, of course. But I've had to install the Certificate Authority on the computer running RabbitMQ server and on the PC connecting to the server.

What was not clear to me on the guide is what happens next. My self-created certificates are just for development. What do I do next to make this a production system?

Answer (score 0):

1. Normally in production systems you have a internal CA maintained by
   your organization. Get your certificates signed by the CA.
2. Also make sure to use TLS v1.2.

Comment: This internal CA is not going to be in the trusted store for all the clients though, so does this mean our CA has to be added to each client PC?

Comment: Normally in a closed network there is an internal CA which sign all the certificates. If that's not the case with you than better get certificates signed by some external entity like CAcert.org  Also use a good cipher suite. You can get all cipher suites supported by installed Erlang runtime rabbitmqctl using : `eval 'ssl:cipher_suites(openssl).` You can check this answer too for more info: [link](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76993/now-that-it-is-2015-what-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-should-be-used-in-a-high-securit?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Just received the CA and the private key file from the hosting team. I'm going to try to generate the certificates needed with these by following the RabbitMQ SSL guide.